# Jquery events are not triggered when loading a view inside a div

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Hi all I am having 2 views I am calling one view from another with in a div, this is my design of view1

```
<div class="page-container">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <span class="navbar-brand">Web Mail</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
                    <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="45" data-offset-bottom="90" class="affix-top">
                        <ul class="nav" id="sidebar-nav">
                            @foreach (var item in Model)
                            {
                                <li><a href="#" onclick="onClick()">@item.folderName</a></li>
                            }
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9" data-spy="scroll" data-target="#sidebar-nav">
                    <div id="mailInbox"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ToDisplayResult"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onClick() {$
            $('#mailInbox').load("/Controller/View2");
        }
    </script>
```

In my second view I have the following design

```
<a id="btnNew" class="btn btn-success" href="#">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Compose
    </a>
<div id='myModal' class='modal fade'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'>Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="popup">&nbsp;Your message has been sent </div>
        @section Scripts{
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#btnNew").button().click(function () {
                        alert('hi');
                    });
                })
            </script>
        }
```

But I am not getting an alert so can some one help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for that is because the `$(document).ready` event is triggered only once, when your main view loaded. Also it is bad practice to put javascript in partial views. I would recommend you doing this in a separate js file:

```
$('#mailInbox').on('click', '#btnNew', function () {
     alert('hi');
});
```

that you will reference in your main view:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
}
```

Notice that I have used the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function to subscribe to the click event of `#btnNew`. This allows to subscribe to events on some elements that do not yet exist in the DOM. Later on, when you make the AJAX call and update the contents of the `#mailInbox` with your partial, the `#btnNew` element will be injected into the DOM and the click subscription will be effective.

So now, all that's left is to get rid of this script from your partial:

```
<a id="btnNew" class="btn btn-success" href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Compose
</a>
<div id="popup">&nbsp;Your message has been sent </div>
```

Comment: Hi `Darin Dimitrov` if I have multiple events do I need bind all them in body event only?

Comment: Not necessarily the body. It could be some parent element. I have updated my answer with an example of using the `#mailInbox` container which will be more effective because we don't need to look for the button inside the whole body but only inside a specified container. And since we know that our button will be added in this container, we could use it as a selector. Also you don't need to put the `.on()` subscription inside a document.ready event.

Comment: If I have one more event I need to bind it to `#mailInbox` based on the requirement ? am I right

Comment: Yes, you could simply make the same selector, just change the event type and target element.

Comment: Thanks but I have div inside the second which I would like to show on button click I tried as follows `$('#mailInbox').on('click', '#btnNew', function () {
        alert('hi');
        $('#modal fade').show();
    });` but I am not getting that div

Comment: OK and what's the problem? Is the `alert` shown? I don't see anywhere in your code an element with `id="modal fade"` so make sure that you are making a proper selector.

Comment: updated the question this is my div `<div id='myModal' class='modal fade'>
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='myModalContent'>Test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: Great, then make sure you are using a correct selector: `$('#myModal').show();`

Comment: Thanks probably some css issue is there I will try it out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99042/discussion-between-demouser-and-darin-dimitrov).

Comment: is there any ready event for div as we have for document.ready